# Is the latest perception_pcl_unstable version usable?

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have been using the perception_pcl_unstable version quite a sometime now. But when i updated the latest version of it which is 227. I was not able to compile it. I can see the below error. I don't want to mess up the rest of my packages and hence i need the version number of the last stable perception_pcl_unstable.

```
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesl_ros: 11.7 sec ]                                                                 [ 1 Active 44/45 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:240:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<pcl::PointIndices>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, pcl::PointIndices>]’
  /workspace/karthik/RRC/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.cpp:137:82:   instantiated from here
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:552:5: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<pcl::PointIndices, void>’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:554:7: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<pcl::PointIndices, void>’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h: In member function ‘ros::Time message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::getVirtualTime() [with int i = 1, M0 = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = pcl::PointIndices, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType]’:
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:646:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::getVirtualCandidateBoundary(uint32_t&, ros::Time&, bool) [with M0 = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = pcl::PointIndices, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, uint32_t = unsigned int]’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:634:65:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::getVirtualCandidateEnd(uint32_t&, ros::Time&) [with M0 = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = pcl::PointIndices, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, uint32_t = unsigned int]’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:763:11:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::process() [with M0 = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = pcl::PointIndices, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType]’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:212:9:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::add(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0, M0 = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = pcl::PointIndices, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:358:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::cb(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, pcl::PointIndices>, typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:290:5:   [ skipping 3 instantiation contexts ]
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:268:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<pcl::PointIndices>, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, pcl::PointIndices>]’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:261:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<pcl::PointIndices>, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, pcl::PointIndices>]’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<pcl::PointIndices>, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, pcl::PointIndices>]’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:247:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<pcl::PointIndices>, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, pcl::PointIndices>]’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:240:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<pcl::PointIndices>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, pcl::PointIndices>]’
  /workspace/karthik/RRC/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.cpp:137:82:   instantiated from here
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:612:117: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<pcl::PointIndices, void>’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:620:119: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<pcl::PointIndices, void>’
  In file included from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h:8:0,
                   from /usr/local/include/pcl-1.2/pcl/pcl_base.h:53,
                   from /usr/local/include/pcl-1.2/pcl/common/io.h:45,
                   from /usr/local/include/pcl-1.2/pcl/io/io.h:43,
                   from /workspace/karthik/RRC/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.cpp:38:
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::Serializer<T>::read(Stream&, typename boost::call_traits<T>::reference) [with Stream = ros::serialization::IStream, T = pcl::PointIndices, typename boost::call_traits<T>::reference = pcl::PointIndices&]’:
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialization.h:161:3:   instantiated from ‘void ros::serialization::deserialize(Stream&, T&) [with T = pcl::PointIndices, Stream = ros::serialization::IStream]’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/subscription_callback_helper.h:172:5:   instantiated from ‘ros::VoidConstPtr ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<P, Enabled>::deserialize(const ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParams&) [with P = const ros::MessageEvent<const pcl::PointIndices>&, Enabled = void, ros::VoidConstPtr = boost::shared_ptr<const void>]’
  /workspace/karthik/RRC/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.cpp:229:1:   instantiated from here
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialization.h:134:5: error: ‘struct pcl::PointIndices’ has no member named ‘deserialize’
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value() [with M = pcl::PointIndices]’:
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:122:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType<M>::value() [with M = pcl::PointIndices]’:
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:139:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_filters.dir/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/workspace/karthik/RRC/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_filters.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/workspace/karthik/RRC/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/workspace/karthik/RRC/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package pcl_ros written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/karthik/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120307-190628/pcl_ros/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< pcl_ros [FAIL] [ 11.79 seconds ]                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pcl_ros. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                            
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                  
[ rosmake ] Built 45 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                        
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] /home/karthik/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120307-190628                                                                 
[ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not detect the following system dependencies as installed: pcl Consider using --rosdep-install option or `rosdep install pcl_ros`
```

I need few clarifications.

1. Does the pcl 1.5 version in the perception_pcl_unstable or is it in the process
2. Do the releases in the pcl standalone and the ros packages happen simultaneously or what is the process being followed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29281/is-the-latest-perception_pcl_unstable-version-usable?/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got the answer from the pcl mailing list

Latest version of pcl is available at  http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2